# mild electric current on the table and case

Tags: power, desktop

I have a UPS to which the case, monitor, etc. are attached. The problem is that when I plug the case (SMPS) power supply cable into the UPS touching the case and the table (on which the computer is kept - metal table) gives me mild shocks (continuously) - but when I plug the case (SMPS) power supply cable into the AC mains - the case and the table are both normal. Plugging the case power into any (of the three) UPS sockets gives the mild shocks.

In both situations (case power from UPS and case power from AC mains) - the UPS itself remains normal (shockless).

What could the problem be?

Could this be solved somehow (for example by connecting the case to the floor or cement wall with wire, etc.)?

Comment: Sounds like a Grounding problem, I would check both the power cord and socket and take it from there?

Comment: It sounds like the UPS isn't properly grounded.

Comment: @Malcolm - Thanks for the quick reply, the UPS has a metal body but it is normal in both situations. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks for the quick reply, the UPS has a metal body but it is normal in both situations. I'm puzzled.

Comment: You can always place the UPS on a ground mat.  But I wouldn't plug devices into a UPS that caused me to get shocked.

Comment: Might be of some help. [Link](http://ask.metafilter.com/146615/My-outlets-are-not-grounded-will-using-a-UPS-and-surge-protector-be-OK)

Comment: I had this same issue and after a few months my PC stopped working. My motherboard had failed. Please beware and ensure there are no ground faults in the circuit.

Comment: Does all the equipment has 3 prong plugs?  Including the outlets on the UPS?